# How can we search the xml files stored in zip files using certain dynamic fields in file system?

Tags: xml, search, xml-parsing

I need to search XML files that are stored in ZIP files to extract data according to certain fields with the help of the file system. What's the best way to search through this data without using DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

Saxon *[disclaimer: my company's product]* can do this using the XPath `collection()` function. For example the XPath expression `collection('dir/file.zip?select=*.xml')/*[title="patent"]/@id` will return the id values of all XML files in the ZIP archive having `title="patent"`.